# use loop to collapse column to list

Tags: r, list, loops

I have many data frames with one column, called "term". Each column needs to be collapsed into a list. 
The following code works for a single data frame:

```
list_1 <- as.data.frame(c("a", "b", "c"))
names(list_1) <- "term"
list_1 <- aggregate(term ~., FUN = paste, collapse = "|", data = list_1)
```

But I am struggling to find a solution for many separate data frames in one go.
I tried the following code but it gives the following error:

> Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) :    '.' in formula and
>   no 'data' argument

```
df.names <- paste("list",1:500, sep="_")
for (i in 1:500) {
  d.frame <- aggregate(term ~., FUN = paste, collapse = "|", data = df.names[i])
  assign(df.names[i], d.frame)
}
```

Another option could be to use a vectorized aproach, but I could use some help here as well.
Many thanks

Comment: How did you create all these separate objects in the first place? It would have been easier if they had all been in a list to begin with. Generally you want to avoid using `assign()` because it just make all other programming in R more difficult rather than using named lists and such.

Comment: Maybe `data = get(df.names[i])`. Note that `df.names` is just a character vector, not actual df's.

Comment: @MrFlick OK totally agree this isn't the best efficient code. Basically I want to transform the original DF to the new df: ```# original
original <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2), term = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"))

# new
new <- data.frame(ID= c(1,2), terms= c("a|b|c", "d|e|f"))
```

Comment: @RuiBarradas thanks! it works like a charm